# Pydroid App: error while installing library

Tags: lib, pydroid

I have a problem for the installation of pycrypto in Pydroid App

see following error

```
pydroid: error: command '/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/ bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc' failed with exit code 1 [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycrypto

Failed to build pycrypto

ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycrypto, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Do you know what I have to do ?
(sorry for my english)

thanks
Dymon

certain libraries are downloaded correctly (cryptography)
I already downloaded Pydroid repository plugin
Library is found

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't `pip install pycrypto` with PyDroid3, but `pip install pycryptodome` worked okay for me.

See: https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/introduction.html.